# How to make an executable file in Prolog

Tags: windows, prolog, swi-prolog

As the question suggest how i can make executable file from Prolog code. I am new to Prolog and learning myself about this programming. I have this simple code which i saved it as `bigger.pl` in root of my drive (in this case D:) and compiled successfully.

```
female(mary).
female(sandra).
female(juliet).
female(lisa).
male(peter).
male(paul).
male(dick).
male(bob).
male(harry).
parent(bob, lisa).
parent(bob, paul).
parent(bob, mary).
parent(juliet, lisa).
parent(juliet, paul).
parent(juliet, mary).
parent(peter, harry).
parent(lisa, harry).
parent(mary, dick).
parent(mary, sandra).


brother(X, Y) :-
parent(Z, X),
parent(Z, Y),
male(X),
X \= Y.
```

I found [this code](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/WinExe.html)  which I inserted in the Command prompt (CMD)

```
plcon -o myapp.exe -c bigger.pl --goal=main
```

After running this script I got this error

```
'plcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file
```

Can you please help.

Comment: plcon isn't being recognised as a command in the command line. You likely need to [update your PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to point to the .exe. Or you can find the executable (or script) and run it directly, eg: `D:\something\plcon.exe -o myapp.exe -c pigger.pl --gloal=main`

Comment: After solving the problem that `plcon` is not found, you must also define a predicate that is called at the start. With `--goal=main` you need to define `main :- ...` somewhere.